# Why do I get a EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) error on a for() line

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I got sent an error log for an app that I've been working on that is experiencing intermittent crashes, generally after working for a 30+ minutes. The exception received in the log is of the type EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT). I haven't experienced the crash myself, and don't have access to the offending device, so the log is all I have to go after when trying to replicate the problem.

After symbolicating the log, it appears that the culprit is the following bit of code (Thread 0 position 10 in the Error log)

```
if(oldStatus != _connected) {
    for(id<OnlineStatusSubscriber> subscriber in _subscribers) {
        [subscriber onlineStatus:self statusChangedTo:_connected];
    }
}
```

specifically

```
for(id<OnlineStatusSubscriber> subscriber in _subscribers) {
```

if the line number is to be believed.

And I can't figure out what might be going wrong here.

Subscribers is initialized in the init of the class

```
_subscribers = [NSMutableArray new];
```

and never thereafter set to nil.

Listeners get added to _subscribers through this method

```
- (void)subscribe:(id<OnlineStatusSubscriber>)subscriber {
    [_subscribers addObject:subscriber];
}
```

and every class that calls that method does use the OnlineStatusSubscriber interface and implement the onlineStatus:statusChangedTo: method.

I've added the Error Log to a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Ux0XRm15

As well as the class in question: https://pastebin.com/NjGcaNxp (where the offending line is line 73)

Comment: Could it be a multithreading issue? E.g. another thread changing the contents of `_subscribers` while this thread is enumerating it?

Comment: Not as far as I can see. The only time subscribers might get changed is in relation to user interaction, and the crashes happen when users haven't touched the device for a long time. The for loop code itself might get called by multiple threads, but simultaneous iteration shouldn't cause a problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I somehow missed that I was unsubscribing from one of the onlineStatus:statusChangedTo: calls. It wasn't even multi-threading, just a direct path. So stupid.

Problem is fixed by iterating over [_subscribers copy] instead of _subscribers.